# passing data from modal form to jquery when editing

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, row, edit

I am trying to edit a row from while loop where at the end of each row there is edit icon. When I clicked edit the modal form is correctly populating the row I selected. But when I save the form it is updating only the first row. I even put the $id in the modal form but the data pushing from modal form to jquery is the first row. See my below code.

Calling the modal form:

```
<img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalFormEdit<?php echo $row['die_id']; ?>" src=images/edit.png height='20' width='20' border=0>
```

My Modal FORM:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFormEdit<?php echo $row['die_id']; ?>" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Die</h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="statusMsg"></p>
                <form role="form">
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dies WHERE die_id = '".$row['die_id']."';";
                    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($db));
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $die_id = $row['die_id'];

                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="editDie1ID1">Die ID (<?php echo $count; ?>)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editDieID" name="editDieID" value="<?php echo $die_id; ?>""/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="editDieDesc">Edit Die Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editDieDesc" name="editDieDesc" value="<?php echo $row["tbl_dies_desc"]; ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="editCustomer">Edit Customer</label>
                        <select class="form-control" name="editCustomer" id="editCustomer" />
                        <option value="<?php echo $row["customer_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["customer_id"]; ?></option>
                        <?php
                        $queryShapes = "SELECT * FROM tbl_client_name ORDER BY Client_Name_DESC ASC";
                        $result = mysqli_query($db, $queryShapes);
                        if( ! $result ) {
                            echo mysql_error();
                            exit;
                        }
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $row['Client_Name_DESC'] . '">' . $row['Client_Name_DESC'] . '</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <br><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="history.go(0)">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitEditDie()">UPDATE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JQUERY:

```
<script>
    function submitEditDie(){
        var editDieID = $('#editDieID').val();
        var editDieDesc = $('#editDieDesc').val();
        //noinspection JSJQueryEfficiency
        var editCustomer = $('#editCustomer').val();

        if(editDieDesc.trim() == '' ){
            alert('Please enter your die description.');
            $('#editDieDesc').focus();
            return false;
        }else if(editCustomer.trim() == '' ){
            alert('Please select customer.');
            $('#editCustomer').focus();
            return false;
        }else{
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'submit_edit_die.php',
                data:'contactFormEdit=1&editDieDesc='+editDieDesc+'&editCustomer='+editCustomer+'&DieID='+editDieID,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
                },
                success:function(msg){
                    if(msg == 'ok'){
                        $('#editDieDesc').val('');
                        $('#editCustomer').val('');
                        $('#editDieID').val('');
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Entry successfully edited! Please close the form.</p>');
                    }else{
                        $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again. </span>');
                    }
                    $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['contactFormEdit']) && !empty($_POST['editDieDesc'])) {

    $editdiedesc   = $_POST['editDieDesc'];
    $editcustomer  = $_POST['editCustomer'];
    $editdieid = $_POST['DieID'];

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");

    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_dies SET `customer_id`='$editcustomer', `tbl_dies_added_date`=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `tbl_dies_desc`='$editdiedesc', `tbl_dies_added_by`='55' WHERE `die_id`='$editdieid'";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        $status = 'ok';
    } else{
        $status = 'err';
    }
    echo $status;die;

    mysqli_close($link);
}

?>
```

Comment: are you sure you getting different DieId for every modal form?

Comment: It looks like you are using `$row` (and `$result`) to represent 3 different sets of data, inside 1 loop.  First what I assume is the main loop to generate your rows.  Then, inside that loop, you do a new query `SELECT * FROM tbl_dies ...` and overwrite the existing `$row` (and `$result`) with something new.  Then another query `SELECT * FROM tbl_client_name ...` which again uses `$row` (and `$result`).

Each of those queries will overwrite the previous values in those variable, so when the outside loops iterate again the original data is gone.  This will certainly mess things up.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. I have 3 different sets of data. I have changed their $row names and even the $result. But still the same issue. Thanks anyway for the response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @DhavalChheda, yes. i have different fields for every modal.

Answer (score 0):

I missed some parts in the hurry, lets break this into proper coding.

- id are unique, never have the same twice
- we don't want data tied datas with the modal so we can have one
  reusable.

Don't loop to print modal, add **just one** like this (with no php) :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalFormEdit" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h1 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Die</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal Body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="statusMsg"></p>
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="editDie1ID1">Die ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editDieID" name="editDieID" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="editDieDesc">Edit Die Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editDieDesc" name="editDieDesc" value=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="editCustomer">Edit Customer</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="editCustomer" id="editCustomer" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal Footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <br><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="history.go(0)">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitEditDie()">UPDATE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changes :

- No PHP
- No Multiple IDS
- No data
- Unique

Now we want the link to give us what we need (honestly it would be better to pass only the id and make a new ajax call to get the other fields) :

```
<img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalFormEdit" data-dieid="<?php echo $row['die_id']; ?>" data-diedesc="<?php echo $row["tbl_dies_desc"]; ?>" data-diecustomer="<?php echo $row["customer_id"]; ?>" src="images/edit.png" height="20" width="20" border="0">
```

Changes :

- Passing parameters with the link (id, infos)...

Last changes is to make a function that will load our modal info (+ the list of customers)

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // WE LOAD THE CUSTOMERS OPTIONS (Once is enough since there is no param)
        <?php
            $queryShapes = "SELECT * FROM tbl_client_name ORDER BY Client_Name_DESC ASC";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $queryShapes);
            if( ! $result ) {
                echo mysql_error();
                 exit;
            }
            echo 'var myClientOptions=\''
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<option value="' . $row['Client_Name_DESC'] . '">' . $row['Client_Name_DESC'] . '</option>';
            }
            echo '\';';
        ?>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // EVERY TIME THIS MODAL POP WE LL LOAD THE RIGHT INFO
        $('#modalFormEdit').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
          var clickedImg = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
          var dieid = clickedImg.data('dieid'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
          var diedesc = clickedImg.data('diedesc');
          var diecustomer = clickedImg.data('diecustomer');
          // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
          // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
          var modal = $(this);
          modal.find('#editDieID').val(dieid);
          modal.find('#editDieDesc').val(diedesc);
          modal.find('#editCustomer').html('<option value="'+diecustomer+'">'+diecustomer+'</option>' + myClientOptions);
        });
 });       
        // REST OF YOUR JAVASCRIPT
```

I haven't been able to try it but you get the idea.
If you donc have other field named editDieID or editDieDesc or editCustomer your ajax function should work, or try being a little more specific in your search : `var editDieID = $('#modalFormEdit #editDieID').val();`

Comment: Thanks bro! I'll give it a try later. Just came back from holidays.

Comment: Got it bro! Guillaume Kiz many thanks.. It's only the </select> close tag. LOL